# JS: Get HTML between comments in a string

Tags: javascript, html, comments

So, I have this HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <div class="parent-wrap">
    <!-- RAW start -->
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Ipsum</p>
    <div>Dolor sit amet</div>
    <!-- RAW end -->
  </div>
  <a href="#">Read more</a>
</div>
```

I need to get the html between the two html comments (without the comments themselves), so just the 2 `<p>` and the `<div>Dolor sit amet</div>`. I get the html directly from the page with `innerHTML`.

Here's my JS:

```
getValue () {
  let html = editor.innerHTML
  let rawStart = '<!-- RAW start -->'
  let rawEnd = '<!-- RAW end -->'
  if (html.search(rawStart) && html.search(rawEnd)) {
    html = html.split(rawStart).pop().split(rawEnd)[0]
  }
  return html
}
```

It works, but I was wondering if there are better ways? Also will this work everywhere? Or are there browsers that modify the html comments (e.g. remove spaces)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.innerHTML` you could use `editor.children` inside a for loop that concatenates all outerHTML properties on the child nodes like so.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <div class="parent-wrap">
    <!-- RAW start -->
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Ipsum</p>
    <div>Dolor sit amet</div>
    <!-- RAW end -->
  </div>
  <a href="#">Read more</a>
</div>
```

```
function getValue() {
  let div = document.querySelector('.parent-wrap');
  let html = '';
  for(let i=0; i < div.children.length; i++) {
    html += div.children[i].outerHTML
  }
  return html;
}
```